# Интерактивная форма на ajax не работает

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-xl-4">
    <div class="input-field">
      <form id="callphone">
       <!-- Hidden Required Fields -->
       <input type="hidden" name="project_name" value="a">
       <input type="hidden" name="admin_email" value="b">
       <input type="hidden" name="form_subject" value="c">
       <!-- END Hidden Required Fields -->
       <input id="phone-email" name="phoneemail" class="form-control" type="text"size="40" required>
       <label for="phone-email" class="animated-label">введите ваш email или номер телефона</label>
      </form>
     </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-xl-4">
     <div class="buttons">
       <div id="sub" class="callback">
         <p>заказать<br> обратный звонок</p>
       </div>
       <div class="send-email">
         <p>отправить<br> e-mail </p>
       </div>
     </div>
</div>

//form email+call
$('#sub').click(function () {
    $('#callphone').submit(function () {
        let th = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "./mail.php", 
            data: th.serialize()
        }).done(function() {
            alert("www");
            setTimeout(function() {
                // Done Functions
                th.trigger("reset");
            }, 1000);
        });
        return false;
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нажимая на #sub, вы всего лишь регистрируете обработчик формы #callphone по событию submit. Регистрация обработки этого события должна происходить до клика, а на клике вызываться метод submit()

как-то так, к примеру:

```
$(function() {
    $('#callphone').submit(function () {
        let th = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "./mail.php", 
            data: th.serialize()
        }).done(function() {
            alert("www");
            setTimeout(function() {
                // Done Functions
                th.trigger("reset");
            }, 1000);
        });
        return false;
    })
})

$('#sub').click(function () {
    $('#callphone').submit()
    return false;
});
```

Comment: большое спасибо - все понятно